# Do I need to normalise, with values from my dataset to train and run inference with GFL for Object Detection?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection

I normally train a resnet101 backbone GFL model. I use MMDetection for this.

```
model = dict(
    type='GFL',
    data_preprocessor=dict(
        type='DetDataPreprocessor',
        mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],
        std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],
        bgr_to_rgb=True,
        pad_size_divisor=32),
```

It includes this in the config of the backbone. My dataset is approximately half the size of the COCO dataset, but I do tend to train from COCO weights. Should I be using a mean and std calculated on my dataset?

The models I train definitely work, but I'm looking for places where I can squeeze out a few more percent of performance, and I'm wondering if this is worth a shot.